# How to handle a task sending a message to a Worker SQS [AWS]

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to decouple PDF generation in order to avoid our customer waiting for it. I have been testing SNS but I read that message order is not guaranteed and I would need to combine it with SQS. I will have only one publisher and one receiver so it does not make sense to me having SNS in the midle. Instead of that I'm trying to create a Worker. My idea is to send the message directly to SQS attached to the Worker. I could create a cron.yml and check every 10 seconds or so, but it feels like a dirty solution.

I have been reading and trying for two days. I could not manage to make this work. I would like to send a message to the queue with the URL and JSON with data just to execute to http://localhost:80/pdf instead of http://localhost:80/ and generate PDF with the information stored in JSON.

Is what I want to achieve possible? I could not find a thing neither in the docs nor in forums. How the worker handle cron.yaml behind the scenes?

Comment: I'm not sure this would work in your scenario, but why don't you have the PDF uploaded to an S3 bucket, which generates an event which will invoke a lambda function to do whatever else you need to do?  This would be less dirty than a cron checking for something every 10 seconds, would give you a secure place for storing the PDF's and is a more AWS inspired method of working.

Comment: I need to generate the PDF, that's why the worker. I was thinking about creating a lambda function, but these PDFs could be very large. Testing several use cases some of them took 5-8 minutes to complete. So running a lambda would be too expensive.

Comment: From what I understand - you have a process that you access via web interface and provide it json data for generating the PDF, which is a time consuming operation. However, I don't understand what the customer interface is here, and if there are other components, what the interaction between them is (and how messaging might help, and where message ordering comes in) - can you please clarify your existing component interaction & customer interface, and what the issue is?

Comment: Users access via web interface to a service which let you can customize cards. You can upload pics and add texts. In summary, our customers could ask for more than 200 cards in one order (having different images). When the customer place the order we have to generate that amount of images and make the PDF with them. The PDF file is mandatory for the printer. A very large PDFs takes a lot of time. Our customer cannot wait 15 minutes when he/she click on the "Order now" button. I want to send a JSON with necessary info to the service in order to give a quick response. Why is this important?